# How to set a variable in a Rebol 3 view and use the value after the window closes?

Tags: scope, rebol, rebol3

I want to set a variable in a Rebol 3 button handler (GUI) and use the value after the window is closed. How do I get the value outside of the view block?
Here is an example code:

```
view [
    v_username:  field
    button "Submit" on-action [
        username: get-face v_username 
        close-window face
    ]
]

probe username
```

The result is "" regardless of the content of v_username.

Does it have to be 'declared' as a global variable? Should I get this value from a returned value of the view?

Comment: Did you set `username: ""` before the view?

Comment: I tried both with it and without it. The result is the same.

Comment: If I don't have that, I get an error:

`** Script error: username has no value
** Where: catch either either -apply- do
** Near: catch/quit either var [[do/next data var]] [data]`

Comment: Confirmed with another variable name. 'username' was probably used in a file I load before with 'do', that's why I didn't get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'on-action` block when invoked is wrapped in a `function` (Rebol function where set-words are assumed local to the function). You have a couple of options to work around this:

1. Use an object to store the values in (set-paths are not bound within `function`):

   ```
   values: context [username: none]
   view [... on-action [values/username: get-face ...]]
   ```
2. Use `'set` to set the word. I find this a little less reliable as it's uncertain the context of the word you are setting:

   ```
   view [... on-action [set 'username get-face ...]]
   ```
3. Though perhaps the best option is to keep in mind that the words you assign to styles are bound the context you're working in, so:

   ```
   view [username-field: field ...]
   username: get-face username-field
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the first option as you suggested and it works. I would love to know though,
why does 1 work? because objects are being passed by reference?
and what's the difference between "x: y" and "set 'x y"?

Comment: I changed my code to use the third option. Who whould have thought that the face name is global and the variable is local. I assumed the opposite.

Comment: When a `funct` is created, it collects `set-word!` types and creates a local context using them. When you reference a word within an object, you are using `set-path!` notation—this is not collected.